# How to convert 2-level nested numpy array to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

we are extracting data from .dlis files (well logs file) using python dlisio library. for most of the companies files data have the same structure, but for one of them the data is stored in nested numpy arrays

the **normal** dlis looks like this:

```
selected_curves_data[0:3]
Output
array([(172600., 1318.3775, 1130.0346, -1130.0301),
       (172590., 1331.5   , 1130.0346, -1130.0301),
       (172580., 1343.5   , 1130.046 , -1130.001 )],
      dtype={'names':['TDEP','A','B','C'], 'formats':['<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4'], 'offsets':[4,8,12,16], 'titles':['T.CHANNEL-I.TDEP','T.CHANNEL-I.A','T.CHANNEL-I.B','T.CHANNEL-C'], 'itemsize':20})
```

the one i am working with has a different structure, each value is nested in a two sub-lists as the following

```
selected_curves_data[0:3]
Output
array([([[6860. ]], [[7.887773]], [[65.23707 ]], [[83.41805]], [[98.60489 ]], [[76.93024]], [[305.9046]], [[  1.435147 ]], [[0.]]),
       ([[6859.9]], [[7.594969]], [[65.16657 ]], [[83.31693]], [[98.35259 ]], [[76.18296]], [[305.8163]], [[-10.156202 ]], [[0.]]),
       ([[6859.8]], [[7.539917]], [[65.115074]], [[83.21918]], [[98.084015]], [[75.37859]], [[305.7146]], [[  2.4681084]], [[0.]])],
      dtype={'names':['DEPTH','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'], 'formats':[('<f8', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1)),('<f4', (1, 1))], 'offsets':[4,12,16,20,24,62,66,1070,1074], 'titles':['T.CHANNEL-I.DEPTH','T.CHANNEL-I.A','T.CHANNEL-I.B','T.CHANNEL-I.C','T.CHANNEL-I.D','T.CHANNEL-I.E','T.CHANNEL-I.F','T.CHANNEL-I.G','T.CHANNEL-I.H'], 'itemsize':1078})
```

I tried the following to convert to the required original structure but then it is not accepting the processed data since the original data type is numpy.dtype[void] but mine is numpy.dtype[float64]

```
a = np.empty_like (selected_curves_data)
selected_curves_data[0:3]
ithRowList = [] 
i=0
for item in selected_curves_data:
   if i < 3:
       print("Type: ", type(item), " shape: ", item.shape) 
       print("----------------------------- Row ",i, " Original ----------------------------- \n", item)
       #ithRowList = np.empty_like(selected_curves_data)
       for subItem in item:
           ithRowList.append(float(subItem))
       
       print("Type: ", type(ithRowList))
       print("----------------------------- Row ",i, " After ----------------------------- \n", ithRowList)
      
       arr = np.array(ithRowList)
       print("Type: ", type(arr), " shape: ", item.shape) 
       print("----------------------------- Row ",i, " Array ----------------------------- \n", arr)
       print("\n")
      
       np.append(a, ithRowList)
       i+=1
       ithRowList = []
          
       
a[0:3]
```

the output is

```
 Type:  <class 'numpy.void'>  shape:  ()
----------------------------- Row  0  Original ----------------------------- 
 ([[6860.]], [[7.887773]], [[65.23707]], [[83.41805]], [[98.60489]], [[76.93024]], [[305.9046]], [[1.435147]], [[0.]])

 Type:  <class 'list'>
----------------------------- Row  0  After ----------------------------- 
 [6860.0, 7.887773036956787, 65.23706817626953, 83.41805267333984, 98.60488891601562, 76.93023681640625, 305.90460205078125, 1.4351470470428467, 0.0]

 Type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  shape:  ()
----------------------------- Row  0  Array ----------------------------- 
 [6.86000000e+03 7.88777304e+00 6.52370682e+01 8.34180527e+01
 9.86048889e+01 7.69302368e+01 3.05904602e+02 1.43514705e+00
 0.00000000e+00]
```

I would appreciate your help
so now it is giving me the following error:

**TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[void]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.**

So my objective is to get a final array same as the original array structure / dimensions, but with values only without having them nested arrays.

so i want the final output to be like this

`(6860., 7.887773, 65.23707, 83.41805, 98.60489,76.93024, 305.9046, 1.435147, 0.)`

this is because further processing will be done based on this structure and i also want columns details that are preserved in the numpy array

Comment: one more issue is that values are changed after each step, i want to maintain same original values with the same format and without the scientific notations

Comment: np.append does not operate in-place.  Read, and reread, its docs

Comment: The 2nd array has more fields, and each fields has a (1,1) shape.  I'd construct a new dtype, with the required fields, but with a field specification as in the 1st.  The copy values to it, field by field.

Answer (score 1):

To copy from the 2nd to the 1st style of dtype - make a target, and copy field by field.

```
In [287]: dt1 = np.dtype([('A','f4'),('B','f4')])
In [288]: dt2 = np.dtype([('A','f4',(1,1)),('B','f4',(1,1))])
```

Make a type 2 array:

```
In [290]: x=np.zeros(3, dt2)
In [291]: x['A']=[[[1]],[[.2]],[[100]]]; x['B']=[[[.0]],[[2]],[[200]]]
In [292]: x
Out[292]: 
array([([[  1. ]], [[  0.]]), ([[  0.2]], [[  2.]]),
       ([[100. ]], [[200.]])],
      dtype=[('A', '<f4', (1, 1)), ('B', '<f4', (1, 1))])
```

the target and copy:

```
In [293]: y = np.zeros(x.shape, dt1)
In [294]: for name in dt2.names:
     ...:     y[name]=np.squeeze(x[name])
     ...: 
In [295]: y
Out[295]: 
array([(  1. ,   0.), (  0.2,   2.), (100. , 200.)],
      dtype=[('A', '<f4'), ('B', '<f4')])
```

I had to use `squeeze` because elements of `x` have shape (3,1,1), while in `y` they are (3,)

Comment: many thanks hpaulj for your answer. but in my case i have thousands of records, and columns names, how can i do it dynamically without hardcoding columns names 'A', 'B' and values ?

Comment: I can imagine changing the `formats` value.  It's a list of tuples, and needs to be a list of different tuples.

Comment: Thanks a lot hpaulj! this solved my problem. I've also written code to create dynamic dtype i will post it shortly